# GQLQuery retrieves empty result set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running a GQLQuery to lookup if a user entered the correct credentials:

```
class User(db.Model):
    UserName = db.TextProperty();
    Password = db.TextProperty();
    Ticket = db.TextProperty();

class Authentication(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        str_user = self.request.get('user')
        str_password = self.request.get('password')
        user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = :1 AND Password = :2",str_user, str_password)
        self.response.out.write(str_user)
        self.response.out.write(str_password)
        self.response.out.write(str([u.UserName for u in user]))

        if user.count() > 0:
            ticket = str(uuid.uuid4())
            user.Ticket = ticket
            self.response.out.write(ticket)
        else:
            self.response.out.write('Not authorized!')
```

The query always return an empty result set (with the "WHERE"-clause) although I'm sure that I've passed the correct parameters.

I've tried to concat my own query string but the result remains the same. If I remove the "WHERE"-clause i get all the users of the db, so I guess the db-connection is okay.

Comment: I *do* hope you're not storing user's passwords in plain text in the datastore.

Comment: Seconded. If possible, you should be using federated login or Google Accounts authentication. If you must store user credentials, hash the user's password.

Comment: Don't just hash it - use a method like PBKDF2. Hashing alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Yeah I know. This is a very small POC-project with 2 users which both belong to me .. I really don't care if my dummy passwords gets stolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you use `TextProperty` on your fields. `TextProperty` is for multi-line texts and is not indexed. You can't lookup for non-indexed values in query. You should use `StringProperty` for single-line text values.

Comment: This was indeed the case. I had no idea google datastore worked like that. Thank you very much. It solved the problem and I learned somethin new today :-)